# java run bash script, command not found

Tags: java, bash, scripting, command

I tried to use java to run some bash script and store the terminal output in a string. However, there are a lot of commands don't work in this way. It keeps showing command not found, but I can run those commands correctly in terminal, ex node --version, go --version. I guess is the path issue, but have no idea how to fix it.

Another question, when I run "python --version", it shows "Python 2.7.10" but it is in getErrorStream. Can anyone give me some hint?

```
public static void runscript() throws IOException {
    Runtime rt = Runtime.getRuntime();
    String[] commands = { "/bin/bash", "-c", "node --version" };
    Process proc = null;
    try {
        proc = rt.exec(commands);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    BufferedReader stdInput = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(proc.getInputStream()));

    BufferedReader stdError = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(proc.getErrorStream()));

    // read the output from the command
    System.out.println("Here is the standard output of the command:\n");
    String s = null;
    while ((s = stdInput.readLine()) != null) {
        System.out.println(s);
    }

    // read any errors from the attempted command
    System.out.println("Here is the standard error of the command (if any):\n");
    while ((s = stdError.readLine()) != null) {
        System.out.println(s);
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you try giving full path to the command instead of just the name. "which node" will give you the path. Try using that in your java code. Also it would be worth to echo $PATH from java to see the difference from that of the terminal

Comment: Concerning "getErrorStream": As you know there are two streams which a program may use to print information on. The program itself decides which one to use. Although there is quite some official guidance where to print what, this is often not handled accurately. In your case, python apparently does that...

Comment: @VishalKamat  I reply it in below. Thanks for great and helpful comment!!

Comment: @EagleRainbow I didn't know about that. I thought it was my like path setting error. Thanks for sharing.

Answer (score 0):

Reply @VishalKamat comment.
when I tried using the output of "which node" as my path, which is "/usr/local/bin/node". It works!!!
But, does that mean I have to change the path when I need to get different application version info?
I thought I can easily get the info just like I do in terminal.

I try to print $PATH by java in this way

```
String[] commands = { "/bin/bash","-c", "$PATH" };
```

The error msg is :

```
/bin/bash: /usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin: No such file or directory
```